# Unity3d UI not responding after Chartboost ad

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, chartboost, unity3d-ui

I have added the chartboost intersitial ad for android unity3d project. Now the ads load correctly and are showing correctly in the scene that i have specified. The issue comes when the user navigates to the ads url. Once the url is opened and if the user uses the android back key to navigate back to the unity3d application, all unity3d UI seems to be non interactive.

I am sure that the unity is not paused at this point as the further android back button activates the quit popup(another UI). Only that even this popup is not interactive.

I am using an Age gate before navigating to the url. The Unity3d version is 5.3.4, with chartboost sdk version 6.3.0.

More Info on the issue:
I tried with replacing the app id and app signature to test ad campaign and the issue goes away. This happens only with the app id we use for cross promotion  ads. Does this have anything to do with the play store app opening the link to the cross promotion as the test ad opening the url in a browser is working fine.

Comment: Finally got it fixed from the chartboost team. Anyone facing the same problem please download the latest chartboost sdk.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check if your EventSystem is in your hierarchy and if there is something between the camera and your ui object.

Comment: EventSytsem is in available in the scene. As you have mentioned some object between the camera and the UI elements, the whole UI works fine if  I dismiss the ad without clicking on it. Anyways i would try to print out all the elements active with the hierarchy one unity activity becomes active.